# PHP MVC: How to exit from Actions/Controllers early?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In a PHP MVC framework, how can I **cleanly** and **elegantly** exit from the current controller/action, but continue normal script execution?

For example, let's say my framework normally follows this outline:

1. Map URL to Controller/Action
2. Instantiate Controller, call Action (capturing output)

   1. Do stuff
   2. Render View
   3. At end of Action method, continue normal operation
3. Process output if necessary
4. Send output to browser

Now, let's say I want to stop "normal" execution somewhere in the "Do Stuff" step to, say, render a different view, or do a header redirect, and I want to stop processing the rest of the body of the Action, but continue onto the "Process output" step

How can I achieve this the best way? My only ideas are:

```
//in controller
protected function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

but this entirely skips the rest of the framework's execution, and dumps whatever was in the output buffer straight to the user. An alternative:

```
//in dispatcher
call_user_func_array(array($controller,$action),$params);
afterwards:
...

//in controller
protected function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
    goto afterwards;
}
```

However, this makes me [twitch](http://xkcd.com/292/) and goes against everything I've learned, especially because the label it's referencing is in another file completely.

So, is there any other way to achieve this?

Note: The redirect example probably should use the `exit()` way, because we're just redirecting to another page anyway and don't care about output. I'm looking for a general-use solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Action method, you can collect all of your output in a string rather than printing it out. Print it out only at the end of the method. If you need to redirect or bail out, then you haven't output anything yet and you can either redirect or return from the method.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could write a custom exception to represent a "Stop normal execution in the 'Do Stuff'" step? It's messy... but it would work.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of that! Granted, it kind of violates the idea of an exception, but it would bubble up until it hits a `catch(EarlyExitException)`, which I could wrap around my dispatch method...

Comment: Exactly... except for the whole "It violates the idea of an exception" as PHP does not yet have a `Throwable` interface.

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional (error) circumstances.  It sounds like "render a different view" is more of a flow control issues.  If so, exceptions should not be used in "normal" conditions.

Comment: @Keith, I agree 120%, but with PHP as it is now, there is no other device that can "bubble" up through the call stack until you stop it. Until PHP has a `Throwable` interface that allows arbitrary objects to be thrown and caught, Exceptions are a uniquely powerful way of controlling flow. That being said, I will probably not implement this method. This is just an interesting use I have not thought of.

Answer (score 0):

you need to abstract much more things. dont just output inside a action! dont set headers as there can go so much wrong before. have different handlers. response handler. handle respons and act depending what you respond. dont just output inside actions. if you have errors throw exceptions catch them with a exceptionhadler and so on.

basic controller action

```
public function view(int $user_id): ResponseHandler {
  $this->validate($user_id); //throws exception

  if (1 == 2) throw new ControllerInvalidArgumentException();

  $view = new View('nameof view');

  return new ResponseHandler($view);
```

}

just have a look at existing frameworks they have very good implemntations of design patterns like laravel or symfony. not sure what you try just dont write your own framework. if you want to learn read and learn from others if you understand whyt they do you will know how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's definitely good to note that a) when I asked this 6 years ago, I was exploring the concepts behind many of the large frameworks by writing my own, and b) PHP was a different beast back then. That said, I do agree with you that the *right* way to do it is to create larger abstractions and build on top of it, but sometimes you want to avoid too much abstraction. IMHO, Laravel and Symfony are great, but are awfully heavy if you just want something simple.

Comment: Nowadays, I tend to favor combining single-purpose libraries to compose a larger PHP framework. [The PHP League](http://thephpleague.com/) has a great collection of libraries to help with this, and there are many many others out there.